# Finding average of columns in an R table

Tags: r, statistics

So I have a table that looks like this

```
Y M1 M2 M3 M4 Total
1 1  1  1  1   4
2 1  2  1  2   8
5 5  5  5  5   5
```

how do I find the average of each row and store that into another table? I've found out about the rowMeans method and did this -

```
rowMeans(h.table, na.rm = TRUE)
```

but that results in an error -

```
Error in rowMeans(h.table, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
as.c.as.num <- function(z){
    as.numeric(as.character(z))
}

rowMeans(sapply(h.table, as.c.as.num), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Calls: rowMeans -> is.data.frame

I get that error

Comment: let me know if the new edit works. If not, I'll just delete so that someone else answers